# How to change background color of an item when the user clicks on

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a listview, when the mouse passes over the items and gives clicking on them, change color.
but when the user clicks on an item and it changes color and the user then clicks on another item, the item previously clicked back to its normal color.
How to make so that when the user clicks on an item, other items not previously clicked on return to their normal color.
As for the user to click on an item a second time, the item returns to its normal color.
Xaml code file of eventons are as follows:

```
 <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.MouseEnter" >
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" >
                                    <ColorAnimation  To="#6990EE90" Duration="0:0:0.3" Storyboard.TargetName="border"  />

                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.MouseLeave" >
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                    <ColorAnimation  To="Transparent" Duration="0:0:0.3" Storyboard.TargetName="border"  />
```

Comment: Set SelectionMode to Multiple

Comment: can you put your complete xaml code for your list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not to do any separate coding or write any trigger for that, just give `SelectionMode=Multiple` or else you can give `SelectionMode=Extended`.

ie.,

```
<ListView SelectionMode="Extended">
//Definition comes here 
</ListView>
```

The difference between these two is that[[Reference]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.selectionmode(v=vs.110).aspx):

**SelectionMode=Extended:** 
The user can select multiple consecutive items while holding down the SHIFT key.

**SelectionMode=Multiple :** The user can select multiple items without holding down a modifier key.

Comment: I turned another drawback, I have a method that when the user clicks on an item of listview item captures, the method ListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown, I before setting the ListView in SelectionMode="Multiple"  it worked. but now that establishes SelectionMode="Multiple", does not work, does not capture the item clicked by the user. What can I do?

Comment: Try `SelectionMode=Extended`